# After editing a question focus set incorrectly

Tags: feature-request, bug

When I edit my question in Stack Overflow,if got a validation error,

```
Oops! Your edit couldn't be submitted because:

    title too long; maximum length 150
```

the focus is not set to error message.So the user got confused what is happen.Better to set focus to the error message itself.
[image: After clicking save button focus move to top position]

[image: Error message is displayed on the bottom.]

Comment: You should upload image of it.

Comment: how can I upload image here?

Comment: Edit your question, and click on the image button (the one that looks like a little picture of a photograph).

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta, but that requires atleast 10 reputation.

Comment: Right. Well, he's got that now.

Comment: trying to attaching screenshots as mention.Edited the post and saved it. But its not showing here.Are you able to see it?

Comment: Yes, we see it ;)

Comment: @Sajith, Just click on the title of the question.

Comment: after clicking the title("After editing a question focus set incorrectly"), I am not able to see the images that I attached to the post!!

Comment: You might have slow net connection at the moment, but others(we) can see the image properly, so don't worry about it.